# Attempting to duplicate a survey in 2007 with content

Tags: 2007

I've tried to make a copy of a survey by saving as a template including content.

When I create a new version of the survey however it does not seem to be getting all of the responses.

My original had 450 responses and when I create a new one based off that template I'm only getting 310 responses.

Any ideas why some responses are not being saved into the template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd hazard a guess that the original response count is possibly including incomplete responses.  I say this is a guess as I always thought that incompleted responses weren't visible to the site admin.

Might be worth doing an SpreadSheet export on both and comparing the differences to see if you can identify some of the missing responses.